# What is the convention C# developers use to indicate their authorship of a class?

Tags: c#, xml-comments

I read from a few places and learnt that there is no author tag in C# XML comments. But I'm sure it is common to come across situations where we have to use some ways to tell people that a particular class is written by who and who.

For myself, I am working on a project with several people and it is sometimes helpful to know who wrote a class, its last modified date, etc.

In Java, there is an `@author`, `@modified`, etc params for comments that will generate to the doc. I am new to C#. Since there is no author tag in the XML comment, what is the convention that C# developers use when they want to indicate that a certain class was written by them?

Comment: That's what source control does.  This comment is not embedded in source control.  So it is Hans™©®.  Copy/paste from this comment as needed.

Comment: I'm with @HansPassant on this one as well. Go to your source control and view history. Doesn't clutter your code with irrelevancies and it's more likely to be right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few professional C# programmers work without source control, and an 'author' or 'modified' tag is completely pointless if you use source control; therefore, there is no convention on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

VB in one of those rare occasions where it's better lets you create a file called VBAxmldoc.xml so you can actually customise the templates for each keyword. C# doesn't have this facility, you could if you've a real desire to do this and you don't have someone like me to get round, create a code snippet with doc comments in it e.g Author. for say creating a class and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using XML [`<remarks>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zw4z1ys%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Or you could do what most devs do and create a `/* ... */` block at the top of the file.